# Assets not found on GitHub Pages Jekyll Blog

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am using the minima theme for jekyll. I want to add images to my posts. In `_config.yaml` I have `baseurl` set to `/blog` and `url` set to `https://mywebsite.com`because my jekyll blog is a separate repo that is accessed by mywebsite.com/blog. In the post I want to include the picture in I have

```
<figure>
  <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/pihole.png" alt="PiHole Dashboard"/>
  <center><figcaption>PiHole Dashboard.</figcaption></center>
</figure>
```

This works fine on my local, but when deploying to github pages the picture is not there. I can access mywebsite.com/blog/assets/main.css no problem, but when I try to access the image it gives me a 404.

Inspecting the page shows me that it does have the correct location

```
figure>
  <img src="/blog/assets/pihole.png" alt="PiHole Dashboard" />
  <center><figcaption>PiHole Dashboard.</figcaption></center>
</figure>
```

Is there something I am missing that is not uploading my image file to GitHub Pages?

Comment: Note: the `<center>` element has been obsolete for many years. Do not use it. Also, the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: It would be helpful if you link to your GitHub repo, otherwise it's a bit of a guessing game.

Comment: @Ross So I solved it by just adding my own assets folder in the docroot. My repo only has a _posts folder, guess because its a gem theme now? Not sure how it all works to be honest. [Link to repo](https://github.com/georgeglessner/blog/)

Comment: It is nice if you create and accept an answer to your own question: assets folder did not exist at the root... This way we all know this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to create an assets folder in my root directory and place the files there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<figure>
  <img src={{ "/assets/pihole.png" | relative_url }} alt="PiHole Dashboard"/>
  <center><figcaption>PiHole Dashboard.</figcaption></center>
</figure>
```

Try relative_url as in [Kitty image is missing in 'Welcome to Jekyll' post but shown at index.md and about.md](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69954620/kitty-image-is-missing-in-welcome-to-jekyll-post-but-shown-at-index-md-and-abo)